# REALM reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'

Tags: swift, realm

I am getting an error when trying to modify a realm object.

It is a simple class and there is actually only one record.

```
class User: Object{

    @objc dynamic var id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var name:String  = ""
    @objc dynamic var email:String = ""
    .....

    static func getInfo() -> User? {
        do {
            let realm = try Realm()
            return realm.objects(User.self).first
        } catch {
            return nil
        }
    }

}
```

I call the data:

```
var user = User.getInfo()
```

And now when I try to modify it I get the following error.

```
user.name = "test"
```

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'RLMException', reason: 'Attempting to modify object outside of a write transaction - call beginWriteTransaction on an RLMRealm instance first.'

what am I doing wrong? Thanks.

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`user` is a Realm instance. Any modifications to `user` need to be within a realm.write block.

```
try! realm.write {
    user.name = "test"
}
```